# Changing color of navbar link and It's hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website using bootstrap but I was not able to change the color of links and It's hovers in navbar. I can't figure out, where should I put the color statement in CSS.

**HTML CODE**

```
 <!-- Navigation -->
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">MG STAV stavební, spol. s r.o</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Domů</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">O společnosti</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="reference.html">Reference</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="contact.html">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: Where's the CSS that you tried? Are you loading your CSS after Bootstrap's?

Comment: Yes, I have my own CSS file overwriting Bootstrap's. Is it necessary to put !important somewhere? @j08691

Comment: Usually no, but that depends entirely on the HTML and CSS rules. Without seeing them all we can do is speculate. `!important` is a last resort.

Comment: Can you look on the CSS file through the webpage? It's address is [link](https://www.mgstav.cz) @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving an ID to all your nav's `<a>` .

```
<a id = "link"....>..</a>
```

CSS:

```
#link{
    color:red; //any other color
}

#link:hover{
    color:black; //any other color
}
```

Working example:http://jsfiddle.net/joez9apm/

Comment: That is not working, I have already tried those easy options.

Comment: @TomášNosek hmm, r u sure ?

Comment: @TomášNosek did you try the css only with the`a`?

Comment: Yes, mine answer above was about the css only with the a tag, but this isn't working as well... @Mohit Bhasi

Answer (score 1):

```
nav a:-webkit-any-link {
color: red;
}

nav a:hover{
color: green;
}
```